# TableView deletion error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am getting the error below from the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[FavouritesController sharedController] removeFavouriteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Please can you tell me how to fix it?

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
>   2011-04-19 21:30:17.854 APPNAME[546:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model before you change your table.

So try:

```
[[FavouritesController sharedController] removeFavouriteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

You probably don't need all those reloads unless the model changes more than just that one index path. The row deletion does some reloading on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [[FavouritesController sharedController] removeFavouriteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```